# How to safely delete a method, how to know if it isn't being used by reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have a method that I know is not references through out my Android project, but I've seen some reflection here and there (its legacy code, Im not familiar with it).
How do I find out if it isnt being invoked by reflection somewhere, so that I can safely delete it?

Comment: Interesting question. It depends on a project but I suppose there is no easy way to do it. For instance if name of method is constructed dynamically in runtime then even quite smart analyzer will not detect such case. I would eliminate all reflection usage from the project or at least put all reflection usage in particular place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a totally general setting, I do not think is possible. You need to check for stuff like

```
Class.forName("some.pkg.here.and.SomeClass");
```

and for

```
Class.forName(packageName + "." + className);
```

The use of reflection can also be hidden behind a library.

It is easier if you have tests. Just delete it and run the tests.

You can also add logging to legacy methods you wish to delete and check it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Depends they use it via reflection: For fullname use you can do a find in files (as text). If they construct it (at runtime), then you will have a bad time at searching.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Android Studio press Alt + F7 on your method (or variable) and it will show all of the usages of it. 
If you use Eclipse try to search on the name of the function in the project directory in total commander for example. 
Please tell me if you need more info!

Comment: I know this, but does this take into account invocations using reflection?